# Dynamic content and routes with browser router in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on this project to learn react, I haven't done dynamic routes before and am struggling with what to do. I have a bunch of playlists, that when click should take you to a page with all the tracks. I have the dynamic route set up and the click functionality working.

My routes look like this

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    element: <Dashboard />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "playlist/:playlist_id",
        element: <Tracklist />
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

I don't understand how to get the dynamic content on the page, the tracklist component won't show up, and the playlist/id subpages are the same as the dashboard page? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tracklist component, you'll need to use the useParams hook provided by React Router. This hook allows you to access the parameters from the URL.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Tracklist = () => {
  const { playlist_id } = useParams();
    
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Playlist ID: {playlist_id}</h2>
      {/* Add your dynamic content based on the playlist_id */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tracklist;
```

This way, when you click on a playlist link, the Tracklist component should render with the correct playlist_id. If you encounter any issues, double-check your route definitions and how you are using the useParams hook.

```
<Link to="playlist/1">Playlist 1</Link>
<Link to="playlist/2">Playlist 2</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have incorrectly nested the playlist route under the `"/dashboard"` route, e.g. the `Tracklist` component is rendered on path `"/dashboard/playlist/:playlist_id"`, and that `Dashboard` doesn't render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render out their `element` content, which is why ***only*** `Dashboard` is rendered on the sub-routes.

Un-nest the playlist route if you would prefer it rendering on `"/playlist/:playlist_id"`.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    element: <Dashboard />,
  },
  {
    path: "playlist/:playlist_id",
    element: <Tracklist />
  },
]);
```

From here it's up to you to decide what it renders. If it needs to react to the `playlist_id` path parameter updating, then use the `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Tracklist = () => {
  ...

  const { playlist_id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // side-effect to run when Tracklist mounts
    // or playlist_id path parameter updates
  }, [playlist_id]);

  ...
};
```